# N integers to be sorted in O(n)?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

Assume you have n integers in the range (0, n2
). These integers are all square roots of other integers.
Indicate whether it is possible to sort these numbers in O(n) or not

I assume we would take square roots of each of the integers but im not sure if its possible to sort them in O(n) any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are willing to use O(n) space:

- You have stored your N integers in array A.
- Allocate a bitmap B with 2n+1 bits, initializated at zero.
- For each integer, set B[A[i]] = 1
- Create an empty list:
- Iterate B in order, so that if B[i] == 1 then i is added to the list.

It can be done in time O(2n) == O(n).